# analyse c# method call bottle neck in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

I have a performance issue with a method call on a dll I have written. The following line gets called

```
lineManage.GetEnquiryLines(ident,null);
```

When calling it from a unit test project the code executes in {00:00:00.5339113}, however when I call the same method from my MVC application it seems to add another two seconds to the time to execute. Both are being run on the same machine.

Does anyone know of any way of identifying what's causing the bottle neck. I've tried using the profiler in visual studio, but that hasn't helped.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use profiler in Instrumentation mode.

Comment: thanks YK1 I will have a look